# How to add column name to cell in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How do I take a normal data frame, like the following:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2
0   1   3
1   2   4
```

and produce a dataframe where the column name is added to the cell in the frame, like the following:

```
d = {'col1': ['col1=1', 'col1=2'], 'col2': ['col2=3', 'col2=4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

    col1    col2
0   col1=1  col2=3
1   col1=2  col2=4
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a new DataFrame containing the `col*=` strings, then add it to the original `df` with its values converted to strings. You get the desired result because addition concatenates strings:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({col:str(col)+'=' for col in df}, index=df.index) + df.astype(str) 
     col1    col2
0  col1=1  col2=3
1  col1=2  col2=4
```

Comment: That's the ticket! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use apply to set column name in cells and then join them with '=' and the values.

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.index+'=', axis=1)+df.astype(str)
Out[168]: 
     col1    col2
0  col1=1  col2=3
1  col1=2  col2=4
```

Comment: Your code give me error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`

Comment: I used `df.apply(lambda x: x.index+'='+x, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
df.ne(0).mul(df.columns)+'='+df.astype(str)
Out[1118]: 
     col1    col2
0  col1=1  col2=3
1  col1=2  col2=4
```

Comment: Your code gives me error `UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U5'), dtype('<U5')) -> dtype('<U5')`