# how to put column name into data frame cell with specific conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataframe like this:

```
         ADR     WD      EF    INF    SSI   DI
0        1.0    NaN     NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
1        NaN    NaN     1      1      NaN  NaN
2        NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN    1    NaN
3        NaN    1       1      1      NaN  NaN
4        NaN    1.0     NaN    NaN    NaN  NaN
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
[["ADR"],["EF","INF"],["SSI"],["WD","EF","INF"],["WD"]]
```

As you see the name of the column has been replaced if there is `1` in that column. and all has been put in another array.

I have looked at this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758159/how-to-add-column-name-to-cell-in-pandas-dataframe) but it did not help me as the name has changed staticly.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['a','b','c']
df1 = df1[df1['c'] == 1]

a = df1.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list).tolist()
print (a)
[['ADR'], ['EF', 'INF'], ['SSI'], ['WD', 'EF', 'INF'], ['WD']]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) it shows 1 in each array, I need to have the name of the column instead of 1. do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - give me a sec.

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - Can you check now? For me it working nice.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why there are three column name? I have 6 columns ?

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - Sure, because you reshape by `stack` - with index values is created first column `a`, with columns names second column `b` and with values is created `c` column.

Comment: Sorry the last question, then what will happen if there is no 1 in some rows? is there any way I can select those rows and delete them?

Comment: Yes, sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - I have no problem with comments :) So is added filtering only values `1` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Comment: Awesome , just for my curisity, what if I want to delete them before applying stack? like there are 6 columns so I want to select rwos in which there are NaN in all columns. I know its may not relate to this directly and your edition answered my question, but for some reason I would like to delete before stack. is there any approach. Thanks :)

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - then use `df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')` in first step - Check also [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: I have an another id column which I did not mention here :D, in that case we can not use this code how='all' . runnnn

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - how='all' and `axis=1` replace all column filled with `NaN`s only. Another `id` column is filled NaNs only?

Comment: No it is like id numbers all field with numbers

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi - So dont worry, it cannot be removed by `dropna`.

Comment: No I meant the result is not correct. Actually I know that its not related to this question, I can simply put and between these 6 columns to check if they are all NaN, later I will learn what is the best solution. thanks for taking your time appreciate it :)

Answer (score 5):

IIUC `dot`

```
df.notnull().dot(df.columns+',').str[:-1].str.split(',').tolist()
Out[753]: [['ADR'], ['EF', 'INF'], ['SSI'], ['WD', 'EF', 'INF'], ['WD']]
```

Answer (score 3):

***Option 1***:
**`replace`**, **`stack`** and **`groupby`**

```
df.replace(1.0, df.columns.to_series()).stack().groupby(level=0).apply(list).tolist()
```

***Option 2***:
**`apply`**:

```
df.apply(lambda x: list(x[x.notnull()].index), 1).values.tolist()
```

Both produce:

```
[['ADR'], ['EF', 'INF'], ['SSI'], ['WD', 'EF', 'INF'], ['WD']]
```